# How can I use an R model to power a cell in a google sheet?

Tags: r, google-sheets, integration, modeling

**I want to use a stats::loess model object created in R to generate a cell's value in google sheets automatically. The input to the function being two other cells in the sheet.**

1. I created a model object using loess() and created a model that
   intakes two features.

   - predict(df, tibble(x,y)) = prediction
2. I want to use this model to power a cell in a google sheet so that non-technical teammates can change the inputs to see what outputs they'd get in different scenarios.
3. I can read and write to a google sheet with R, but I want someone shared on the google sheet to have the output value live-updated if they change the input values.

**Is there a way to do that?**

Comment: Convert your model as API using plumbeR function. Host that model locally or on cloud. Next, write a call in google sheets to do API calls to your model. Here is some reference material for google sheet script editor https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/beginner-apis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that's possible. You can only interact with googlesheets when a manual trigger is fired like when you run to edit cells in googlesheets or download values from a sheet. To have a dynamic platform I recommend using shinny.